# jemalloc dirty page setting

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, malloc, out-of-memory

I am running server program on 32 GB machine. RSS goes up and free memory keeps getting lower. Eventually when free memory reaches 400 MB, it does not goes down. At some point application needs some large memory say few gb and it dies. We are using jemalloc. I suspect jemalloc caching dirty pages. My questions are :
1. How to display dirty memory setting in running process. 
2. How to change dirty page that jemalloc can have. 
P.S. We have ran valgrind to verify no memory leak under test run. Application is in C++ and multithreaded. Also surprised why stackoverflow does not have jemalloc tag :)

Answer (score -2):

lg_dirty_mult did the trick. 
Actual value is 2^lg_dirty_mult.

Answer to 2nd part : 

MALLOC_CONF=stats_print:true,lg_dirty_mult:0 application_executable 

this can also be done at run time by mallctl() with the "opt.lg_dirty_mult" parameter.

Answer to 1st part : used malloc_stats_print from jemalloc lib.

Link helped : 
 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=811740
https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: As an incentive, I downvoted both of them. Fix the formatting and I will remove the votes. Cheers.